# How do I create a map that displays only polylines that contain a particular attribute value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

We have had a consultant create 7 options for a series of remote road networks. The options share segments so Option A contains segments 1 to 6, Option B contains segments 1 to 5, 7 and 8, Option C contains segments 1 to 5, 7 and 9, Option D contains segments 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11 and 12, etc.

I have added an Option field in the attribute table so that segment 1 has Option "ABCFG", segment 2 has Option "ABCFG", segment 3 has Option "ABC", etc. So I can query to select Option contains "A" for all segments that are part of the "A" option.

Now, I'd like to display only those selected segments and create a printable map.

How do I do this? (Or maybe I need to do it differently)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query will be:

```
Option LIKE '%A%'
```

The wildcard character `%` matches zero or more characters.

You can display only those features using the query as a Definition Query in the layer's Properties, or using Select by Attributes then right-click the layer and choose Selection > Create Layer From Selected Features.